# Is it possible to set the background of a new tab page to a HTML file?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I was wondering if it was possible to set HTML code as a background for chrome.

Here is a edited example: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpXbB.jpg) (Replace green with HTML output)

I was going to insert this HTML code into the background:

```js
particlesJS('particles-js', 
 {
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 80,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 800
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#ffffff"
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": "circle",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "img/github.svg",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
      }
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 0.5,
      "random": false,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 1,
        "opacity_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 3,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 40,
        "size_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": true,
      "distance": 150,
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "opacity": 0.4,
      "width": 1
    },
    "move": {
      "enable": true,
      "speed": 3,
      "direction": "none",
      "random": false,
      "straight": false,
      "out_mode": "bounce",
      "bounce": false,
      "attract": {
        "enable": false,
        "rotateX": 600,
        "rotateY": 1200
      }
    }
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "grab"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "push"
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 100,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 400,
        "size": 40,
        "duration": 2,
        "opacity": 8,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 200,
        "duration": 0.4
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": true
});

window.onscroll = function(){
  var navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar')

  if (window.pageYOffset > 49){
    if (navbar.classList.contains('transparent')){
      navbar.classList.remove('transparent')
      navbar.classList.add('opaque')
    }
  }else{
    if (navbar.classList.contains('opaque')){
      navbar.classList.remove('opaque')
      navbar.classList.add('transparent')
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JS particles example</title>

    <style>
        #particles-js {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #49A8EB;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: 50% 50%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            z-index: -1;
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="particles-js"></div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/svginjector/1.1.3/svg-injector.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js'></script>

<script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way possible to do this? If so, I would love to know!
P.S. I've already tried looking this up and trying things out.

Comment: Can not load index.js and app.js (404 error). Are they any important? I do not quite get it. What do you mean by Replace green with HTML code?

Comment: Sorry about that, It has been fixed now.